# Chef attributes in files

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a file under

```
cookbooks/recipe/files/default/file
```

where I need to add the default attribute `<%= node['hostname'] %>`.

I know I could put the file below `templates/`, however I need it to be under `files/`.

I am having the attribute defined above to work, Chef doesn't parse the file it looks like. Since on the node the files comes in raw text.

How can this be solved? Since the same variable worked with files under `templates/`, what is the difference?

Comment: The difference is the difference between templates and files - templates can have variables in them. Why can't you put it in templates/ ? Any other solution is a bandaid.

Comment: What's that `cookbooks/recipe/files/` path? You mean `cookbooks/<cookbook-name>/files/`, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr *You can't.*

The difference is exactly what you encountered. The [`cookbook_file`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html) resource copies the original file from the cookbook, while the [`template`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) passes it through the [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) templating engine.

You can't do that with the `file` resource. Just use a `template` resource instead (and move it to `templates/`). This procedure is totally normal, when you decide that you have to make a file parametrized. I don't believe your argument "I need it to be under `files/`". Just move it.